# Interact with an action in an API style controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I'm making an Ruby on Rails app where I have:

`routes.rb`:

```
Test::Application.routes.draw do
  get "api_error/404"

  get "sss/home"

  root :to => "home#index"

  match "/zad0xsis" => "home#pablo"

  match "/sss" => "sss#home"

  match "/api/1/:api_action" => "api_v1#runner"

  match "/api/" => "api_error#api_not_found"

  match "/api/:api_version/:api_action" => "api_error#api_not_found"

  match "/api/:api_version" => "api_error#api_not_found"

  match "/api/1/:api_action/:whoiscool" => "api_v1#runner"

  match "/whoscool/:whoiscool" => "api_v1#whoscool"
end
```

`api_v1_controller.rb`:

```
class ApiV1Controller < ApplicationController
  def runner
        response.headers["Content-Type"]                = 'application/json'
        response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = '*'
        response.headers["server"]                      = `hostname`

        @output = {'api_version' => "1", "error"=>false}    

    case params[:api_action]

        when "register"
        register

        when "whoscool"
        whoscool

        else
            @output['error'] = true
            @output['error_code'] = 106
            @output['human_error'] = "API Function not found (or not authorized)"
        end
        # Set Output
        @output = JSON.generate(@output)
        # Turn Off Layout
        render :layout => false
  end


#--------------------------
# Register Action
#--------------------------

  def register
    @output['hello'] = "true"
  end

  def whoscool
    @output['cool is'] = params[:whoiscool]
  end
#----- ADD NEW FUNCTIONS ABOVE THIS LINE -------#

end
```

`whoscool_controller.rb`:

```
class WhoscoolController < ApplicationController
def index

end
end
```

I need to know how to make `whoscool_controller.rb` call `api_v1_controller.rb` `runner` for making it call the action `whoscool`. If I access to `api/1/whoscool/zad0xsis` I get the correct JSON output, but I'd need to get that output when accessing `whoscool/zad0xsis` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I hear you correctly, what you want to do is have two different paths call the same functionality but with different formats, just add a couple of routes for that, like this:

```
match 'whoscool/:id' => 'whoscool#show'

scope 'api/v1' do
  match 'whoscool/:id' => 'whoscool#show', :format => 'json'
end
```

And then make the `WhoscoolController` handle the different formats:

```
class WhoscoolController < ApplicationController
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { ... }
      format.json { ... }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: And how would I do for calling the `api_vi whoscool def` with `:id`as arguments? As I said, I'm just starting with RoR

Comment: You won't. You'll do this in `WhoscoolController#show`. There you can access the id from `params[:id]`.